# Best practice to return calculated data in an ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my first question on stackoverflow.com. I'm an aspiring, self-teaching Asp.NET developer. I greatly enjoy answering other people's questions (I spend a lot of time answering Udemy beginner questions) and one day I hope to be able to contribute to Stack Overflow in the same way.

Quick general story on the project:
I'm making an API using Asp.NET Core that allows users to clock in and clock out of a jobsite. Both Users and Jobsites can have multiple timestamps thanks to a many-to-many relationship. All basic crud functionality is working and I can successfully check to see who has clocked in to a jobsite and/or where a user has clocked in. My end goal is to finish the API and then create a React App to consume it.

The Question:
I'm now going to attempt to create routes that return more 'complex' information. I want a user route to be able to return general stats based off the timestamps in the database for that particular user. When hitting this route, I want to return a DTO with calculated information such as the following:

- Total hours worked in the last 7 days/2 weeks/month
- Jobsites worked at in last 7 days/2 weeks/month
- a router that allows taking in 2 dates to filter timestamps in the last x amount of days/weeks/months

The logic for the above I actually have to still figure out as it's going to be a bunch of DateTime sorting that I need to learn, but the question is, what is the best way to perform the above and return these calculations in a JSON object? Here is what I was considering -

A) Create a helper class that will store all the methods for calculating the above data, call these methods one by one in the user controller, build a DTO on the spot and return it.

B) Create a DTO with GET properties that will do all the calculation there inside (is that possible? I'd need an example for this one), use Imapper to map the entity to the DTO, return the DTO.

C) Do this logic on the client side, maybe this isn't typical behavior for an API? (I'm a noob).

D) A solution that isn't any of the above

What is the best coding technique for the above? Thank you very much for the time.

Robinson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 3 recommendations based off of your question. But I will mention that opinion based questions typically aren't what is recommended for Stackoverflow.

1. Use a dedicated viewmodel/DTO that you will populate inside of your controller with the results of the various function calls you do to get that calculated information. That will keep the responsibility of that model limited to just the result returned by your API, and not get inflated by information irrelevant to your client.
2. If you're doing complex work, or work that just takes time, have it behind a POST action, not a GET. This will help avoid having browsers attempting to pre-emptively retrieve/fetch the information in instances where it's not needed yet, or when that route/action will have an impact on performance of your site/app/server
3. Lastly, look at caching the result of this work. Either in the controller, and return the previous result if it was generated under X minutes ago, or alternatively using ResponseCaching and let the web server cache the entire response.

EDIT: As for the caching, you can add response caching, you can do that by adding `services.AddResponseCaching();` to your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method, and then decorate your action like so

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60 * 60 * 24 /* 1 Day */)] //Cached for a day
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff()
```

or if there's a querystring parameter in there for example...

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60 * 60 * 24 /* 1 Day */, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "someIdentitifer" })] //Cached for a day
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff(int someIdentitifer)
```

If you want to cache inside your app instead of HTTP cache, you can look at doing this manually using `MemoryCache` or at a third party package that does it like [LazyCache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazyCache) (not affiliated with them)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the time in answering. I'll do as you suggested in #1. As a follow up question, can you elaborate on your #2(Edit: I saw your edited answer ) #3 is beyond me hehe. As for the question, I figured it involved asking for coding technique, which seems to be allowed.

Comment: Technique vs opinion is a super blurry area to me, but I'm not that picky, more just bringing it up because I've been stung with closed/flagged questions because of it too :-)

Comment: Added some details about caching. I didn't go into great detail, but there should be enough key points that you can use some google-fu and find some examples on doing it in aspnetcore (since your original question was not about caching)